# Using web input to build conditional Docusign response

Tags: docusignapi

I'm only mildly technical and not the web lead for my company, but I am the membership lead and I'm hoping to use your API for my workflow.  This is what I need:

A web form on our website that asks for Name, e-mail, age, and a drop-down box of predetermined locations.

Using the above, I'd like the age to decide whether the requestor receives the Over 18 or Under 18 version of my form.  Then I'd like the name to be auto-filled into the correct form.  I'd like the form to be then e-mailed to them for a signature, and I'd like the signed, returned form to not only come to my primary e-mail address, but also to use the location to send a carbon copy to their local representative.

Can it be done?  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use DocuSign to easily achieve the workflow you've stated.  There's probably several ways you can implement this, I'll focus on the first that comes to my mind which is using `DocuSign Templates`.

Using Templates you can upload documents into your DocuSign account at design time, add workflow, tabs, routing, etc, then at run-time your app can reference these templates and match specific recipients to placeholder roles configured in the template.

For example, your flow would be:

1. Create 2 templates in your DocuSign account, one for 18+ case and one for Under 18 (note: you have unlimited templates in your account).
2. Add a Carbon Copy recipient as the second recipient for each template, make sure to give a `routing order = 2` by setting the signing order.
3. Once your web form receives all input data from the user (ie Name, email, age, and location) use the [Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) API to create an envelope with the form data populated in various tabs.
4. By default, once they are done signing the platform will email them a copy of the signed document (you can control this through account settings).
5. The Carbon Copy recipient will also receive a copy of the signed document once signing is complete, you can store a static email in the template or provide new recipient information at run-time when making the API request.

For more info see the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/).  I also recommend you have a look at the [Tabs](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) section and [Templates](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates) section for some highly useful information.